# How I can add parameter to request from jersey filter request (ContainerRequestFilter)

Tags: java, spring, filter, jersey, jetty

I am use Jersey + Spring. I have Jersey filter which implements ContainerRequestFilter, and i need transfer object in my jersey resource.

For example:

```
@Provider

public class UnmarshalEntityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnmarshalEntityFilter.class);

@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {

    final String xml = getRequestBody(containerRequest);
    // Parse this xml to Object

    // How I can add this Object to my request and get from Jersey Resource ?

    return containerRequest;
}

private String getRequestBody(ContainerRequest request) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        if (in.available() > 0) {
            ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

            byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
            sb.append(new String(requestEntity, "UTF-8"));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ContainerException(ex);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

See the [`ContainerRequest#setProperty(String, Object)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ContainerRequest.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method which states

> In a Servlet container, the properties are synchronized with the
>   ServletRequest and expose all the attributes available in the
>   ServletRequest. Any modifications of the properties are also reflected
>   in the set of properties of the associated ServletRequest.

So you can simply call

```
final String xml = getRequestBody(containerRequest);
containerRequest.setProperty("xml", xml);
```

then inject the `HttpServletRequest` in your handler and access it with `HttpServletRequest#getAttribute("xml")`.

**With Jersey 1.17**, the corresponding method is [`ContainerRequest#getProperties()`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequest.html#getProperties%28%29) which returns a mutable `Map<String, Object>` to which you can put attributes that will be synchronized with the `ServletRequest`.

You can retrieve a property in your Jersey resource from [`HttpContext`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/HttpContext.html):

```
@Context
private HttpContext httpCtx
...
final String xml = httpCtx.getProperties().get("xml")
```

---

On a different note, careful consuming the request `InputStream`. If some other component in your stack needs to read from the stream as well, it will fail.

Comment: @Malahov Which version of jersey are you on?

Comment: <jersey.version>1.17.1</jersey.version>

Comment: @Malahov I'm not certain with this [javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequest.html#getProperties()). But you should be able to get the `Map<String,Object>` with `ContainerRequest#getProperties()` and `put` your object into it and it will be synchronized.

Comment: I put this xml to properties: containerRequest.getProperties().put("xml", xml); but from request (in resource) a get null value.

Comment: @Malahov Is the filter actually being hit? Make sure with a logging statement. Otherwise, I've run out of ideas.

Comment: After call put method, i am logging this property and it do not null

Comment: I am using Jersey 1.17, and also don't find the property in `HttpServletRequest#getAttribute()` but rather in `httpContext.getProperties()` (it's injectible via `@Context com.sun.jersey.api.core.HttpContext httpContext;`).